# QSqlQuery not giving correct results when selecting TINYINT column

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I have a very simple MySQL Table and want to select some of the rows using QSqlQuery.

I am connected to my local development mysql server (Windows; 64-bit).

When I run a SELECT query with other tools like mysql workbench, I always get the correct results (of course!).

Doing the same with QSqlQuery gives me no rows at all!

```
QString sql = "SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `ModbusID`, `DeviceType` FROM `Devices`;";

qDebug() << sql;

QSqlQuery query(m_db);
if(!query.prepare(sql))
{
    qFatal("could not prepare query");
    return;
}
if(!query.exec())
{
    qFatal("could not execute query");
    return;
}

while(query.next())
    qDebug() << "result";

qDebug() << "finished.";
```

SQL-Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Devices` (
    `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `MeasurementID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `ModbusID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `DeviceType` INT NOT NULL,
    `TimestampCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `TimestampLastModified` DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY(`MeasurementID`) REFERENCES `Measurements`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (`MeasurementID`, `Name`)
);
```

[image]

In both programs I am connected to the same local mysql instance. There are no other mysql servers on my machine or on the network.
This happens with Oracle's MySQL and MariaDB! So the problem must be in my program.

Am I doing something wrong or what's happening here?

**UPDATE** After multiple tests the problem only occurs when I select `ModbusID`. I changed the table definition from

```
    `ModbusID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

to

```
    `ModbusID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

and now it works. Looks like [a bug in QT](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55153). But I dont think that this is a good solution. If you know a way to use `TINYINT` then please write an answer or comment!

Comment: Did you try executing "SELECT ID, Name, ModbusID, DeviceType FROM Devices WHERE MeasurementID = ?;"

Comment: Just tried it. Result is the same!

Comment: what type is `devices`? would you please show us the declaration?

Comment: Mike, I just removed `devices` from the example. I hope my problem is more clear now.